# Second .wav file plays enhanced noise of first .wav file instead of reduced noise

Tags: python, audio, scipy, pyaudio

I am trying to achieve active noise reduction in python. My project is composed of two set of codes:

1. sound recording code
2. sound filtering code

What I aim for is that when you run the program, it will start recording through the microphone. After you've finished recording there will be a saved file called "file1.wav" When you play that file, it is the one that you recorded originally. After you're finished with that, you will now put "file1.wav" through a filter by calling "fltrd()". This will create a second wav file in the same folder and that second wav file is supposedly the one with less/reduced noise. Now my problem is that the second wav file is enhancing noise instead of reducing it. Can anyone please troubleshoot my code? :(

Here is my code below:

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.io.wavfile
import scipy.signal as sp

FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
CHUNK = 1024
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "file1.wav"

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# start Recording
stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE, input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
print ("recording...")
frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)
print ("finished recording")


# stop Recording
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
audio.terminate()

waveFile = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
waveFile.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
waveFile.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
waveFile.setframerate(RATE)
waveFile.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
waveFile.close()


x = scipy.io.wavfile.read('file1.wav')
n = x[1]
y = np.zeros(n.shape)
y = n.cumsum(axis=0)

def fltrd():
    n,x = scipy.io.wavfile.read('file1.wav')
    a2 = x.cumsum(axis=0)
    a3 = np.asarray(a2, dtype = np.int16)
    scipy.io.wavfile.write('file2.wav',n,a3)
```

Comment: What is your basis for thinking that a cumulative sum of an input signal results in a "less noisy" output signal? It doesn't, as you've discovered. Actual noise reduction is a very complicated topic, but you can [start over on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_reduction) which mentions some algorithms you could look into.

Comment: @TypeIA it was suggested by a fellow member here as I've asked about this problem before. Here is the link to my past post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49607395/value-error-occurs-when-filtering-wav-file

Answer (score 2):

Actual noise filtering is difficult and intense. However, an simple noise filter using high and low pass filter can be easily created using pydub library. See [here for more details  (install, requirements etc)](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub)

Also [see here](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/pydub/effects.py#L187) for more details on low and high pass filter using pydub.

Basic idea is to take a audio file and then pass it through both low and high pass filter such that audio above and below certain threahold will be highly attenuated (in effect demonstrating filtering).
Although, this will not affect any noise falling in pass-band for which you will need to look at other noise cancellation techniques.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub import low_passfilter
from pydub import high_pass_filter
from pydub.playback import play

song = AudioSegment.from_wav('file1.wav')

#Freq in Hz ,Adjust as per your needs
new = song.low_pass_filter(5000).high_pass_filter(200)
play(new)
```